# Render router Children ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi guys So I have a page on my website with a sidebar as this drawing shows 
[page Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hMJZ.jpg)

The drawing shows my page which is a child of app.
I am currently trying to render a child component in the area labelled
{this.props.children}.
Currently my page renders without the content of the child component. 
just blank.

Here is my Router set up

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={LandingPage}/>
    <Route path="serviceitem" component={FullService}>
      <IndexRedirect to="trial"/>
      <Route path="trial" component={Trial}/>
    </Route>
    <Route path="services" component={Services}/>
    <Route path="specials" component={Specials}/>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

And this is how I am trying to render my component children

This is ServicePane Component
    
     
     SideBar
     
     
      {this.props.children}

This is FullServicePane

```
    <div>
     <NavigationBar/>
     <ServicePane/> 
    </div>
```

FullService Contains

```
 <div>
    <FullServicePane/>
    <div className="row">
     <BottomBar/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Need more info, I'm assuming the component shown above is your App component? Can you paste the full content of landing page app as well as your imports and exports?

Comment: are there any error messages in the console?

Comment: Also perhaps `SideBar` should be rendered as a component `<SideBar />`

Comment: I apologize I think I found the error It was a child of a child, which let me to believe I was nesting too deeply and ended up reworking my ui into less code and it worked out

Answer (score 0):

I apologize I think I found the error It was a child of a child, which led me to believe I was nesting too deeply and ended up reworking

my actual Components were

```
FullService-> 
FullServicePage ->
  ServicePane ->
    Trial
```

In this instance Trial was a child of ServicePane and not FullServicePane